# How to submit a form on the key press and input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that include text input for search. I want to submit the form when the users hits enter in the text input if its value is not null or equal to `Search...`, here is my code:

```
<form 
     action="<?php echo MAIN_URL."search"; ?>" 
     method="post" 
     onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 && this.getElementByName('search').value!='') { this.submit(); }">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="Search..." onclick="if(this.value=='Search...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search...';" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't really want to have "Search..." as /value/ of your input box at any time. These days you use `placeholder` attribute, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
```

Browser support varies (old IE...), but there are polyfills available. Overall: cleaner, better solution.

You don't need to include any JS to auto-submit your form on `enter`, but here is some code that prevents submitting the form with it as long as your text `input` is empty:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && $('input[type="text"]').is(':focus')) {
    if ($('input[type="text"]').val().length < 1) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o6fn7eor/1/

(I took liberty to use jQuery, as you tagged your question with it)